# Nginx реверс-прокси в докере

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, прокси

Пытаюсь настроить nginx реверс-прокси в докере, пробрасывающее в .net приложение, вот мой docker-compose:

```
version: "3.1"

services:
  web:
    image: imperialplugins/steam-openid-connect-provider:latest
    container_name: web
    ports:
      - 3000:80

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    links:
      - web
```

Dockerfile самого прокси:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Eranga Bandara (erangaeb@gmail.com)
# install nginx
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
# deamon mode off
RUN echo "\ndaemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx
# volume
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx/sites-enabled", "/etc/nginx/certs", "/var/log/nginx"]
# expose ports
EXPOSE 80 443
# add nginx conf
ADD config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /etc/nginx
CMD ["nginx"]
```

и nginx конфиг:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     steamconnecttest.com www.steamconnecttest.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://web:3000/;
    }
}
```

Приложение работает через localhost:3000 как положено, однако при обращении просто к localhost получаю лишь стартовую страницу nginx, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте поменять `proxy_pass  http://web:3000/;` на `proxy_pass  http://web/;`, т.е. перенаправлять на порт 80. Это необходимо, т.к. `- 3000:80` говорит о том, что у вас внутри сети `Docker` в контейнере ваш сервис работает на 80, а вы его "открываете" для внешнего мира на 3000 порту, отсюда и получается что внутри контейнера с `nginx` никакого 3000 порта не будет.

Также, возможно, для вас подойдет уже готовый официальный [образ](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx) `nginx`, вместо того, чтобы собирать его самому.

Comment: большое спасибо, смена http://web:3000/; на http://web/; действительно помогла. :)